# Preciso remover essa borda circular que o background-color que eu inseri está deixando ao redor do ícone, alguém sabe o como fazer?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

HTML:

```
        <div class="contato">
            <a target="blank" href=""><img src="/icones/instagram.png" alt=""></a>
            <a target="blank" href=""><img src="/icones/whatsapp.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.contato{

    border: 1px solid white;
}

.contato a{

    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.contato img{

    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #E87051;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(226,83,82,1) 0%, rgba(232,112,81,1) 50%, rgba(246,150,63,1) 100%);

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Meu como que tu quer usar um background em uma tag <img>?

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que remova está linha de códico

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(226,83,82,1) 0%, rgba(232,112,81,1) 50%, rgba(246,150,63,1) 100%);
```

Como é uma tag img não precisa de background ...